# Repository layout with Ivy in Artifactory

Tags: ivy, artifactory

We are using Ant+Ivy and I am a newbie on Artifactory. One very basic question is that we always publish resolved `ivy.xml` along with artifacts into the Ivy repository, but in Artifactory, I am confused if we should publish `ivy.xml` or `pom.xml`? Artifactory suggests to use a maven2 compatible layout so it's easy to migrate to Maven in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can store both ivy.xml and pom files in Artifactory, it will give you the ability to migrate to maven (if you wish), although Artifactory fully support [automatic conversion of layouts](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts) from ivy layout to maven2 layout and vice versa. You can also use the convention user plugins to [generate ivy.xml out of pom.xml](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/pom2ivy) and [vice versa](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/ivy2pom) as well.

[Here are the docs on Artifactory Ivy support](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+with+Ivy).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Since all our projects use Ivy, does it matter which repo layout (maven-2-default vs ivy-default) we use if we choose to use an existing repo or create a new repo?

Comment: Ivy layout is more useful for Ivy since it allows Ivy indexing mechanism without `maven-metadata` files (since the top level directory lists all the group ids).

P.S. Did you find the answer useful? Vote. Did it solve your problem? Accept.